# onclick event in a link with zurb foundation tooltip on touch device

Tags: onclick, touch, tooltip, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Zurb Foundation framework (2.0) and have a tooltip on a link.

```
<a href="" id="delete-preference" class="has-tip" title="Delete" onclick="return someFunction(0);">x</a>
```

On a desktop it works fine, the tooltip shows on mouseover and you can click the link to trigger the someFunction

On a touch device however the tooltip shows on click/tab. But that way you are not able to trigger the onClick event and the someFunction.

How could you do this?

Answer (score 4):

Find:

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
    $body.on('click.tooltip touchstart.tooltip touchend.tooltip', settings.targetClass, function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
```

Replace

```
e.preventDefault();
```

With

```
if($(settings.tooltipClass).css("display") != "block")e.preventDefault();
```

Should be fixed.